# Python replace multiple strings from a .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

I would like to use the .replace function to replace multiple strings with in a .txt file, to run my servos. My .txt looks like this: A5,0,500,1,400.

```
 data_dict = {} 

for line in data:

    line = line.replace("\n","","","")

    line_list = line.split(",")

    Object = line_list[0]
    num_one = line_list[1]
    num_two = line_list[2]
    num_three = line_list[3]
    num_four = line_list[4]


    data_dict[object] = [num_one, num_two, num_three, num_four]
    pass

return data_dict
```

The problem is here: line = line.replace("\n","","","")

This is the error: TypeError: replace() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

It works with line = line.replace("\n","") but that is just one servo, I need to run two.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `replace` as an instance method, you must only use 3 arguments. The first argument (the string) is implicit. This is why you see the error.

Further, you can use `len(line)` as a cheap way to replace all occurrences without knowing how many there are -- there can only be at most the number of characters in the string.

```
line.replace("\n", "", len(line))
```